# Friendship Query - PHP & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

below is my query which returns session user's friends.

```php
   $new_friends = $db->query("
   SELECT user.id, user.name_surname
   FROM user
   JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.sender_id or user.id = friendship.receiver_id
   WHERE (friendship.receiver_id =" . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . " OR friendship.sender_id =" .  $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . ")                  
   AND user.id != " . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . "");
   $new_friends->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $new_friends_data = $new_friends->fetchAll();
```

It is working good, there is not any problem about it. Now I want to improve my site with new properties so I want to add "NEW PEOPLE" section to my site. Fetched people must not session user's friend and hisself/herself.

I tried to use below code for "YOU MAY KNOW" section. But it is returning again session user's friends.

```
  $new_friends2 = $db->query("
  SELECT user.id, user.name_surname
  FROM user
  JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.sender_id or user.id = friendship.receiver_id
  WHERE (friendship.receiver_id !=" . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . " OR friendship.sender_id !=" . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . ")                  
  AND user.id != " . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . "");
  $new_friends2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $new_friends_data2 = $new_friends->fetchAll();
  //look carefully I change some equations from = to !=
```

How can I fix it?

Basically I want to return people who are not session user's friends.

Comment: @Mihai ı think in my code ses id is not important because basically I want to return people who are not session user's friends

Comment: You should be using AND in the WHERE clause for the second part, not OR.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (friendship.receiver_id !=" . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . " OR friendship.sender_id !=" . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . ")
```

OR here allows one of those columns to have SES_USER_ID change it to AND

Comment: I change "or" to "and" still it is returning friend

Comment: Could you post some sample data?Whats is the difference between the 1 and 2 query?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough!

But looking at the question, you should replace `or` with `and` !!